# GWT vs SmartGWT

Tags: performance, gwt, comparison, smartgwt

Can you please let me know which of the option( `GWT or SmartGWT`) is better, considering the below scenario.

1. Will be used for designing screens and client-side validations.
2. Performance ( page loading , grid loading) should be good.
3. Need to communicate with server through soap (web services.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [GWT vs SmartGWT, extJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038392/gwt-vs-smartgwt-extjs)

Answer (score 1):

I used both SmartGWT and GWT and both have pros and cons.

SmartGWT:
+ have existing and complex widgets ready to use with nice layout that can be used for production as it is
+ quite nice support
+ if you decide to pay also very nice communication mechanism 
- problems starts when they do not have widget you need or when you want to change their widget
- the API of the widgets is unclear, there are logs of methods from parent methods that do not have impact on its children

GWT: 
+ The API is very clear (in my opinion) 
+ The widgets can be extended in every way you can imagine 
- The out of the box layout is not ready for production. You have to change it (CSS) if you want nice layout

The choice depends on what is important for you.

Answer (score 1):

While you are at it, consider using MVP with GWT. GWT will soon become an unmaintainable monster if you don't stick to an organized pattern of development (I guess this applies for all frameworks).  For MVP with GWT, give [GWTP](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/) a read.

Comment: The pureMVC is also worth mentioning. It goes fits MVC pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the designing screens. Both can be done in the GWT Designer ( Eclipse ), but eventually your application is gonna be big and the use of the designer is not practical.

Here you can check the speed of smartgwt

http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/

And here of normal gwt

http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html

There isn't really much difference in performance. I'm using SmartGwt myself and it is really nice to develop an application quickly with pre-exisiting widgets. You can have the interface setup in no-time with smartgwt.

There is also a possibility of combining smartgwt and gwt ( which is not recommended ).